# WPF TPL Restart a canceled Task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Here’s my problem: I cancel a Task with a Click Event which works fine. Now I want to restart the Task by clicking on the same start event which started the Task initially. 
The “error” that I get is that I get the MessageBox Information (“Stop Clicked”). So I’m “stuck” in the Cleanup Task.

How do I solve this?
Help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Here’s my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{   CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
}
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;      
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();  
    po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
    po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

    Task dlTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {   do
                {  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                   Parallel.For(0, dicQueryNoQueryURL.Count, po
                            , i =>
                            {   token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                if (!token.IsCancellationRequested){// do work
                                }
                            });
                }
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
            }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    dlTask.ContinueWith(
                (antecedents) =>
                {       if (token.IsCancellationRequested){
                        MessageBox.Show("Stop Clicked");
                    }
                    else 
                    {    MessageBox.Show("Signalling production end");   }                
                    dlTask.Dispose();
                }, uiScheduler);
}
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ cts.Cancel(); }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try simply creating a new CancellationTokenSource and generating a new Token when you click Start.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();           
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
...
```

From the books online:

> One cancellation token should refer to one "cancelable operation,"
>   however that operation may be implemented in your program. After the
>   IsCancellationRequested property of the token has been set to true, it
>   cannot be reset to false. Therefore, cancellation tokens cannot be
>   reused after they have been canceled.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much! also thank you for the excerpt!
I still have alot to learn :(